# How do I control output after executing a command?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

```
..
Script Run Complete.
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/<user-name>
-bash-3.2$
```

I have seen the above message most the times on my prompt, probably while it's idle or as soon as script returns or just upon hitting return. I won't be needing it, at all.

Is there any way/tweak to control whats being output on the prompt? How would I be knowing if it's going to show up there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do `unset MAILCHECK`. From the bash manual:

> ```
> MAILCHECK
>        Specifies how often (in seconds)  bash  checks  for  mail.   The
>        default  is  60 seconds.  When it is time to check for mail, the
>        shell does so before displaying the  primary  prompt.   If  this
>        variable  is  unset,  or  set  to  a  value that is not a number
>        greater than or equal to zero, the shell disables mail checking.
> ```

You can e.g. put it at the end of the your `/.bashrc` or search that file and/or `/etc/bash.bashrc` if MAILCHECK is set anywhere and remove it.

The alternative is that you read the mail and make sure no new mail arrives...

Comment: @Keys Which part of "From the bash manual" did you miss?